# Performance issue with Hard Drive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10

My Desktop components are about 15 months old whose configuration is:

- Processor: AMD FX 8320,
- Motherboard: Asus M5A97,
- HD: WD Black Internal Drive (WD1003FZEX),
- RAM: Kingston HyperX Fury DDR3 16GB (HX318C10F/8 x 2),
- SMPS: Cooler Master 650W and
- Graphics Card: 2GB Saphire 5450
- Installed OS: Windows 10

I have been facing following Issues for last 4-5 months:

- Most of the time, when I start my computer or restart my computer, after Windows Logo and spinning circle, its stuck on black screen and on black screen I see only mouse cursor, and no changes for a long time. Even no changes after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd>.
- When I press <kbd>Reset</kbd> button on cabinet, it starts up normally.
- Apart from this, while working on computer, I see very frequently that the mouse cursor is busy for 10-15 seconds (even in idle mode).

What I did:

- Checked startup apps and services (msconfig),
- Changed HD SATA Cable and plug-in different port.
- Cleaned RAM and plugged in another socket,
- Did full scan with an Internet Security apps,
- Configured "No Page File"
- Re-installed Windows

However, the issue not resolved.

My Desktop configuration is good but because of this problem, its performance is not good.

Answer (score 0):

May not directly be helping, but just to check, have you ever been checking the disk for errors and let them get repaired?

- inside Windows 10 -> This Computer -> Right-click Disk C: -> Properties -> Tools -> Check disk -> Check device .
- maybe better by an elevated command -> chkdsk c: /r (note, includes /f) -> answer Y for the next restart -> Re-start the machine (chkdsk will take the machine for an hour, or so).

By the way, why "No Page File", wasn't the machine slowering, a bit or much with the 16GB RAM?

Answer (score 0):

Try checking that WD Black with [WD Data Lifeguard Diagnostic](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=zlUXft) and see if the drive passes both the quick and the extended tests. This should show you if the drive itself has any issues.

Check if you have any pending BIOS, OS or driver updates. The OS updater might be attempting to perform some actions and thus causing such issues.

Check if you have any background applications that cause the system to stutter. The resource monitor should show you if anything uses up resources and bottlenecks the system's performance.